# Is it possible to focus an open "Global Search" via hotkey without having it first close?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can press the hotkey `cmd + shift + f` to open the global search. This focuses the input so I can type my search term.

Once open, I might start making edits to various files. This means that my focus is now on the document.

To refocus the search to type another term, or updated the current one, I can use the same hotkey, but it first closes, then reopens the search.

This might be something that's better to submit as an issue, but I wanted to first check and see if there was something that I might be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adjusting my keybindings.json file as follows.

```
{
  "key": "shift+cmd+f",
  "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
  "when": "searchViewletVisible && searchViewletFocus"
},
```

Here, I simply added `&& searchViewletFocus`.

This made it so that if I was focused anywhere but the global search, my keyboard shortcut for "View: Toggle Search" would now focus an open search instead of closing it.

To close, I'd simply enter the command again while focused on the open search.

Answer (score 0):

It exists a related setting to do this natively.

With default shortcut on mac:

- `cmd`+`shift`+`f` ➡️ focus search input
- `cmd`+`shift`+`e` ➡️ focus search editor

---

Here's the setting that you are looking for :

[image: The relevant setting]